# Android Delete All record SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, record

I am new to Android with a button and I would like to delete all the records in the Sqlite db according to the year chosen by the spinner.
That is, if I choose the spinner, 2013, the pressure of the Button must be eliminated all the data entered in that year. Obviously in the db there is a field of type TEXT in which is inserted the date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd".

```
 @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


    SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, null, null);

}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question. If the question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have tried and what problems you are encountering. After all, the `delete()` method on `SQLiteDatabase` seems fairly straightforward, so it is unclear what part of what you are trying to do is giving you trouble.

Comment: You're right, I entered the code with the delete () method but it deletes all records. But I want to delete only records inserted by the year chosen in spinner ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The second and third parameters to the `delete()` method on `SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) allow you to specify a SQL `WHERE` clause (and values for positional parameters) to constrain which records get deleted.

You, instead, are passing `null`.

Replace the `null` values with a valid `WHERE` clause (e.g. `"your_column_name_goes_here LIKE ?"`) and `String[]` array of positional parameters (containing the value to replace the `?`).